# Regex - pegando determinados valores - PHP

Tags: php, regex

Estou numa dúvida, tentei ler vários artigos sobre expressões regulares, mas ainda não encaixou na minha mente, fico confuso.
Tenho uma determinada string

```
vid..0002-3f3c-458c-8000__vpid..e29ac000-8020-395e__caid..8ff77872-a0cb-4d7c-a36c0bd6__rt..D__lid..a1b926-17da-45b8-8bfc-32464ba72cdd__oid1..7ef55782-6c4b-414e-b7b9-faa2d55b32e1__oid2..a2292a00-31ce-4366-b6c6-72a0204b38be__var1..%7Bname%7D__var2..MLPUBID__var3..%7Bheadline%7D__var4..%7Bimage%7D__var5..%7Badid%7D__var6..%7Bad%7D__var7..%7Bage%7D__rd..__aid..__sid..
```

No meio dessa string, cada atributo é separado por __. ou seja, é mais ou menos como se cada __ fosse uma virgula e o .. fosse igual.
Usei essa gambiarra

```
$str = str_replace("..", "=", $_REQUEST['voluumdata']);
$str = str_replace("__", ", ", $str);
preg_match_all("/([^,= ]+)=([^,= ]+)/", $str, $r); 
$voluum = array_combine($r[1], $r[2]);
```

Eu gostaria de algo mais direto, que pudesse separar na expressão regular os elementos, e se possível pegar apenas os oidN, ou seja, oid1.. oid2... etc

Comment: Necessito saber, se a variável, assim como a valor podem ter qualquer carácter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ora, se atributos são delimitados por um `__` e seus valores por `..` é muito simples realizar essa tarefa de extração:

```
<?php
# É sua string principal, da qual se quer extrair
$str = 'vid..0002-3f3c-458c-8000__vpid..e29ac000-802 ...';
$split = explode('__', $str);
# um array (chave => valor) representando os atributos
 $results = array_map(function($e){
    return explode('..', $e);
}, $split);


print_r($results);
```

Não é necessário fazer uso de expressões regulares pois, nesse específico caso, não é pragmático além de ser menos explícito quanto ao que se quer chegar. Separando a string por trechos com explode e ajustando os pares de (atributo=valor) é mais prático e menos "nebuloso".

Aqui está uma versão executável do código:
https://3v4l.org/WapO5

Comment: Usei a técnica do outro usuário, mas o seu também funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a REGEX que você necessite seja esta:

```
([^\.]+)\.{2}([^_]*)_{0,2}
```

Seja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uQ3zO2/1)

#### Explicação

```
([^\.]+) = Grupo 1, vai pegar qualquer coisa que não seja '.', no minimo 1 vez  
\.{2} = literal '.', ira capturar '.' duas vezes
([^_]*) = Grupo 2, var capturar qualquer coisa que não seja _, 0 ou infinitas vezes
__{0,2} = captura do carácter _ no final para suprir e não ser capturado pela var.
```

#### PHP

Para recuperar seus valores no PHP sera assim:

```
preg_match_all("/([^\.]+)\.{2}([^_]*)_{0,2}/", $str, $match);

$vars = array();
foreach($match[1] as $k => $options){
    $vars[$options] = $match[2][$k];
}
```

Comment: Usei a sua técnica, parece ser um pouco mais rápido, valeu cara